# telethon .get_entity() freezes my program

Tags: python, python-asyncio, telethon

I use Telethon to pars the list of subscribers to a Telegram channel and Telebot to install the parser in the Telegram bot. I also use asincio. In the async function, when the program reaches the line with
`channel = await client.get_entity(url)` everything stops.

I tried creating a task instead of using `await`, but nothing changes. The other coroutine functions, that I made, works correctly (program continues work). How can I solve this problem?
Thank you for any helps!

PS: some pictures of Call Stack while debugging: before, and after `...get_entity(url)`
[before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hSZpU.png)
[after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eWiYw.png)

UPD: The output is totally empty because there is no exceptions or warnings, just freezing. But I've changed this line to channel = await client.get_input_entity(InputPeerChannelFromMessage('Channel', message.id,message.chat.id)) and it doesn't freeze.
I also noticed that get_entity("t.me/channellink") works correctly when I use it without Telebot library. Maybe that's the reason...

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please include the output of enabling `logging.DEBUG`, as that may contain hits necessary to solve the problem.

Comment: The output is empty because there is no exceptions, just freezing. But I've changed this line to `channel = await client.get_input_entity(InputPeerChannelFromMessage('Channel', message.id,message.chat.id))` and it works. But in line `participants = await client(GetParticipantsRequest(channel,
            filter_user, offset_user, limit_user, hash=0))` I've got: a TLObject was expected but found something else
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_bytes'

Comment: That's a different error entirely. `get_entity` shouldn't really be freezing. `DEBUG` logs should show more information.

Comment: The exception 'TLObject was expected..' appear because of incorrect `channel` variable. So the solving problem with `get_entity()` will help to find out what's wrong, I hope...